DRAM0 overflowed in ESP32 Arduino
I am using Espressif ESP-WROVER-KIT for a machine learning image classification task. The board has a RAM of 320 KB. When I build the code, I am getting following error:

region `dram0_0_seg' overflowed by 10079520 bytes

My main.cpp is below:
#include "model.h"  // Include the model header file

#include <tensorflow/lite/micro/all_ops_resolver.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_error_reporter.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_interpreter.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/schema/schema_generated.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/version.h>
#include <Arduino.h> 

// Globals, used for compatibility with Arduino-style sketches.
namespace {

  tflite::MicroErrorReporter micro_error_reporter;
  tflite::ErrorReporter* error_reporter = &micro_error_reporter;

  const tflite::Model* model = nullptr;
  tflite::MicroInterpreter* interpreter = nullptr;

  TfLiteTensor* input = nullptr;
  TfLiteTensor* output = nullptr;

  // Create an area of memory to use for input, output, and intermediate arrays.
  constexpr int kTensorArenaSize = 10 * 1024;
  uint8_t tensor_arena[kTensorArenaSize];
  const uint8_t image_data[128*128] = {
    0, 0, 0, ..., 255,  // Example values
    // ... (rest of the data) 
    }
}  // namespace

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Load the model
  model = tflite::GetModel(model_mobilenetv2_tflite);
  if (model->version() != TFLITE_SCHEMA_VERSION) {
    Serial.println("Model schema version does not match");
    while (1);
  }

  // Create an interpreter to run the model
  static tflite::MicroMutableOpResolver<10> micro_op_resolver;
  tflite::MicroInterpreter static_interpreter(
      model, micro_op_resolver, tensor_arena, kTensorArenaSize, error_reporter);
  interpreter = &static_interpreter;

  // Allocate memory from the tensor_arena for the model's tensors
  interpreter->AllocateTensors();

  // Obtain pointers to the model's input and output tensors
  input = interpreter->input(0);
  output = interpreter->output(0);

  for (int i = 0; i < input->bytes; i++) {
    input->data.uint8[i] = image_data[i];
  }
  
}

void loop() {
// Run the model on this input and make sure it succeeds
  if (interpreter->Invoke() != kTfLiteOk) {
    Serial.println("Invoke failed");
    while (1);
  }

  // Output the results
  for (int i = 0; i < output->dims->data[1]; i++) {
    Serial.print("Output[");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print("]: ");
    Serial.println(output->data.uint8[i]);
  }

  delay(1000);
}


I have also tried to check my .dram0.bss in the .map file. I found out that .dram0.data is of 0x9b9abc size (10 MB). So, .dram0.data will not fit in region dram0_0_seg. But how can i compress the data.
Any idea what is wrong? I

I have tried to reduce kTensorArenaSize, but no help.

Please do not use the comment space for adding info - edit & update your post instead.
